# How to copy latest files from source folder to dest folder in same sftp using pentaho

Tags: pentaho, vfs, pdi, pentaho-data-integration

I have to copy the latest file from source folder to destination folder in same sftp location using pentaho.

i have tried with "copy step"step from kettle jobs by providing sftp source and destination details in file/folder source and file/folder destination.

while executing i am getting error like "File system exception : could not find file in the files /path" and "unable to get VFS file object for filename" .

i have declared below vfs configurations:

vfs.http.proxyhost: host details
vfs.sftp.StrictHostkeyChecking : no

please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SFTP specific job entries instead, as with Copy files you need to specify username and password on the url and that's not safe. Both Get files and put files with SFTP support username/password and private key authentication.